# MongoDB using parameter for nested location

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parameters, nested, location

have a little newbe problem although I couldn't find a solution for similar problems, that worked for me.
Here is my collection:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5bc712851224ceec702d9bdf"),
   "index": "123456",
   "name": "Jan",
   "surname": "Nowak",
   "grades": {
     "IABD": [
       2,
       3.5,
       4 
    ],
     "NPAD": [
       4,
       4,
       5 
    ] 
  } 
}
```

now I need to push additional grades to specific (function parameters) courses.

So I tried tackling it on a few levels and I'd love somebody to walk me through it according to this:
First I wanted to succeed not passing course as a parameter:

```
function add_grade(index="123456", course="IABD", grade=5.5) 
{
db.students.update( {"index" : index }, { $push: { "grades" : { "IABD" : grade } } } );
}
```

well nothing happened (grade was not added to the list of grades)
I wanted to see some result, so I wanted to see if $set would work and it did!

```
function add_grade(index="123456", course="IABD", grade=5.5) 
{
db.students.update( {"index" : index }, { $set: { "grades" : { "IABD" : grade } } } );
}
```

but it threw away my entire grades object (as expected). At least I know I'm on the right track.
**Question 1: Why $push didn't work the way I expected**

**Question 2: how to use course parameter in set/push?**
Just to clarify Q2, I'm not lazy, I've tried many approaches, none of which worked, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query. That push `6` into `IABD`

```
db.getCollection('students').update( { "index": "123456" }, { $push: { "grades.IABD" :  6 } });
```

Comment: it doesn't do anything. There is no errors or anything, but the collection is left unchanged. However, if I change your query to $set, then it works (but it's set, when I need push)! Nevertheless, I still don't know how to use course parameter for push/set

Answer (score 0):

[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) is not working the way you are expecting because the array field is in an embedded document and to push you need to use
[dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) i.e. instead of

```
{ "$push": { "grades" : { "IABD" : grade } } }
```

what you need is to specify the field as [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)

```
{ "$push": { "grades.IABD" : grade } }
```

To use the course parameter in push you would want to create an update object that holds the dot notation

```
{ "grades.<course>" : grade }
```

for example

```
var course = "IABD";
var grade = 5.5;
var update = {};
update["grades." + course] = grade;
printjson(update) // prints { "grades.IABD" : 5.5 }
```

So your function will look like

```
function add_grade(index="123456", course="IABD", grade=5.5) {
    var update = {};
    update["grades." + course] = grade;
    db.students.update( 
        { "index" : index }, 
        { "$push": update } 
    );
}
```